Firefox extension, Xray Vision
I am writing a firefox extension. It should intercept calls to functions like eval or innerHTML.
For now, I am unable to do that as firefox prevents overwriting these properties. Despite even using XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap or window.wrappedJSObject methods.
How do I achieve what I need, possibly in any other way?

The mozilla docs say the content script may execute some code inside a target page. To do so it's needed:
window.eval(`
<here goes the code that will have access to the page's window and objects>
`);

